# VOIP application - MediaElement output on ear-piece

Tags: windows-phone-7, voip, mediaelement

I am developing a SIP based VOIP Application and stuck  on following issue,

1 -- I am Able to play with the SIP Protocol and Server and able to get Audio data in PCM 8000 Sampling rate format,

2 -- for Playing Audio i am using MediaElement framework, and using this framework its giving output in SmartPhone multimedia Speaker, Is there anyway to get default output on the Ear-Piece, and let user to choose, whether they want to attend the call trough Speaker or through Speaker,

it seems WP8 has got this support, but i didn't find it for WP7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

Unless, you'll contact Microsoft and negotiate yourself a privilege to compile native ARM code. Some companies (e.g. Tango, Spotify, Garmin) did.